# Removing '70's carpeting from outdoor cement stairs

Tags: outdoor, removal, carpet

I have a mid-century ranch house in the Seattle area (moisty, mossy). A previous owner decided to apply green "outdoor" carpet to the stairs and back step.

I give the carpet credit for lasting maybe 35 years, but it has deteriorated to the point where it is peeling off and a danger to anyone who uses the stairs.

I want to remove the carpet entirely, but it is glued down and is putting up a fight against mere pulling.

**Question:** Can anyone recommend a way to remove the carpet before someone gets hurt? A bio-friendly solvent to help get rid of the glue? Soaking the carpet in water? Some kind of scraping tool perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no easy way, this will require mechanical removal. Try starting with a long-handled floor scraper:

[image]

Then you will likely need to remove residual adhesive with a razor scraper:

[image]

images stolen shamelessly from ubiquitous internet search engine